# How to use Keybase Git repository in Termux

Tags: android, git, termux, keybase

Keybase-cli installs and runs in Termux on Android. However, I can't figure out if using the git helper is supposed to work in that environment or not.

If I add a remote from Keybase (i.e. keybase = keybase://private/user/repo) and run
`git fetch keybase`,

I get the message

> git-remote-keybase error: (1) keybase isn't running: try 'run_keybase'

This script cannot be found, though. Have others tried this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As Murphy's Law states, one finds an answer only after posting the right question.

An [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/17203) shows that the magic command is

`keybase service`

After this, Git with Keybase repositories works fine.